# Why re-render only happens when state defined in the Provider wrapper component changes, not when value supplied to Context.Provider changes?

Tags: react-hooks, react-context, react-state-management, rerender

I have developed a library for managing state through Context with React in an easy and optimal way. Its name is [react-context-slices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-slices). It behaves great and optimal, as far as I know and I could have tested and checked. But here is my question, if you look at the source code I do:

```js
    return (
      <StateContext.Provider value={{ [name]: state }}>
        <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
          {children}
        </DispatchContext.Provider>
      </StateContext.Provider>
    );
```

and the behaviour or result of this is that the components fetching or consuming this Context (`StateContext`) only updates or re-renders when `state` changes, which is great, because is what I want and is the optimal behaviour. But I can't figure it out why this happens. In theory, I should have done something like this:

```js
    const value = useMemo(()=>({[name]: state}), [name, state]);
    return (
      <StateContext.Provider value={value}>
        <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
          {children}
        </DispatchContext.Provider>
      </StateContext.Provider>
    );
```

But as I say in this case the behaviour, as far as I could have tested, is the same using `useMemo` or not using it. And I can not understand why the first case, without `useMemo`, behaves as it does, that is, only updating (rendering) components consuming the `StateContext` when `state` changes.

I would understand this behaviour if the source code were:

```js
    return (
      <StateContext.Provider value={state}>
        <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
          {children}
        </DispatchContext.Provider>
      </StateContext.Provider>
    );
```

which is not. As I say the value passed to the provider is `{[name]: state}` and not `state`, but the behaviour is as if I passed `state` and not `{[name]: sate}`.

Can anyone explain to me why is this "good/optimal" behaviour happening.

Comment: From a quick glance at your code, there is nothing else but `value` changes that will trigger a rerender in your provider. So this is really the only possible behaviour you could see.

Comment: @super thanks for "answering" me so fast, but I cannot understand your comment. Can you elaborate on it a little more, please?

Comment: `useMemo` would only serve a purpose if the provider rerenders but `value` stays the same. But the only time the provider rerenders is when `state` has changed. If you would add a second `useState` to your provider and updated that without changing `state`, you would see a difference with and without the `useMemo`.

Comment: hello @super, I added an answer to my own question. regarding your comment, I must say that `Provider` seems to rerender each time, despite `state` staying the same and `value` changing. As I say in my own answer it's only when `state` changes that component consuming Context updates.

Comment: https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer#setstate-caveats

Comment: @super, oh yes, I see! It's written in the documentation. Thanks a lot for pointing me to it. I will edit my own answer to reflect that fact. Great job and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is the correct behavior. It looks like no matter what value you pass to the Provider of the Context, the component consuming it will only re-render if the state defined in the Provider wrapper component changes. For example:

```js
// provider.jsx
import { createContext, useReducer, useContext } from "react";

const StateContext = createContext({});
const DispatchContext = createContext(() => {});

const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "set":
      return typeof payload === "function" ? payload(state) : payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const useMyContext = () => useContext(StateContext);
export const useMyDispatchContext = () => useContext(DispatchContext);

let id = 0;

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { foo: "bar" });
  console.log("rendering provider");
  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{ ["value" + id++]: state.foo }}>
      <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </DispatchContext.Provider>
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Provider;
```

```js
// app.jsx
import { useMyContext, useMyDispatchContext } from "./provider";

const App = () => {
  const value = useMyContext();
  const dispatch = useMyDispatchContext();
  console.log("value", value);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "set", payload: (s) => s })}>
        =
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "set", payload: (s) => ({ ...s }) })}
      >
        not =
      </button>
      {JSON.stringify(value)}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In the above situation, each time you press the `=` button, `rendering provider` gets written in the console. But no `value` is written in the console, that's it, `App` doesn't rerender. It is not until you change the state in the provider by pressing `not =` button, that the `App` gets rendered again.

Here is the sequence:

[sequence in the console result of the interaction with the buttons = and not =](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZmWR.png)

So the conclusion is that when using Context like this, it only updates components consuming it when `state` changes, not when `value` changes. **And the reason for this is what [@super](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7703024/super) pointed me to in his comment to my own question**. Is written in the React [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer#setstate-caveats) regarding the `useReducer` hook:

> If the new value you provide is identical to the current state, as determined by an Object.is comparison, React will skip re-rendering the component and its children. This is an optimization. React may still need to call your component before ignoring the result, but it shouldn’t affect your code.

Here "value" refers to the `state` value. This explains why the `rendering provider` appeared in the console, as the sentence **"React may still need to call your component before ignoring the result"** says.

Thanks [@super](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7703024/super) for giving me the answer to this apparent mystery.

I must add that you have to keep in mind that despite React ignoring the result, the component was called, so if you change the `current` value of a ref in its execution (or change a global var as I did), it will stay changed after that. This is something to keep in mind.